# format of object for addClass, add text and remove li using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using object for addClass, append text and remove li. I want to is my object format and my function is good to go or it can be done with better code. Also I am separating class and text using comma. In my second object declaration i am not appending text so I want to know which key does not contains text property. Last thing is that it is not removing last li. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fcZv4/)

**jQuery**

```
  function updateli(x) {
    $.each(x, function (val, key) {
        if (Array.isArray(key)) {
            $.each(key, function (i, val) {
                $('li').eq(val).remove()
            })
        }
        $('li').eq(val - 1).addClass(key.split(',')[0]).text(key.split(',')[1])
    })
}
$(function () {
    var ob = {
        2: 'bggreen, hiii',
        3: 'bgblack',
        remove: [0, 3]
    }
    updateli(ob)
})
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li>to be remove</li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li>to be remove</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, can you rephrase it ? Just tell, what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to know which key does not contain second property. Like 3:'bgblack' contains only one and 2:'bggreen, hiii' contains two property

Comment: can we loop in key also ?

Comment: I think, you are making the simple thing more complicated, can you tell what exactly your goal is with the `li` and `object` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use an object, instead of "," separation and then spliting...
the problem with the deleting is, that you delete [0] first, but then the index of the li's isn't at the same position, so [3] isn't anymore it is now [2]...

```
function updateli(x) {
    $.each(x, function(key, val) {
        if (Array.isArray(val)) {
            var $lis = $("li");
            for (var i = $lis.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (val.indexOf(i) > -1)
                    $lis.eq(i).remove();
            }
        } else {
            $('li').eq(key).addClass(val.class).text(val.text)
        }
    })
}
$(function() {
    var ob = {1: {class: "myClass", text: "myText"}, 3: {class: "myClass"}, remove: [0, 3]}
    updateli(ob)
});
```

here the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/reyaner/6dzAM/1/)

Answer (score 1):

you can save split result like this

```
$.each(x, function (val, key) {
    if (Array.isArray(key)) {
        $.each(key, function (i, val) {
            $('li').eq(val).remove()
        })
    }
    var keys = key.split(',');
    var $li = $('li').eq(val - 1).addClass(keys[0]);
    if(keys.length > 1){
        $li.text(keys[1])
    }
})
```